# Filter View based on a column in lookup list

Tags: 2010, list-view

I have got 2 lists call Applications and Vacancies. Application has a lookup filed pointing to Vacancy. And Vacancy list has got a user field called "Hiring Manager". I need to create a view under Applications list and filter this list based on the associated hiring manager from vacancy table. 
I tried to use Linked datasource, but when I create it, although I select columns, I cannot see anything in the datasource pane.

Could you give me, please, an idea how to create such view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the two list web part in a page and create a connection as follows.

1. Click "**Connections**" from web part menu of Application list.
2. Click  "**Get Filter values from**" Vacancies list.
3. Select "**Provider Field Name**" as Manager name column.
4. Select "**Consumer Field Name**" as Vacancy lookup column.
5. Click "**Finish**".
6. Save the page.

Now if you click on the arrow icon under "**Select**" column, corresponding values will get filtered in the next web part

[image]